# Issue using funcaptcha in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, captcha

I am Trying to implementing fun-captcha(http://codecanyon.net/item/fun-captcha/163632) in cakephp.

```
$this->CaptchaGenerator = new CaptchaGenerator();
$this->set('captcha0', $this->CaptchaGenerator->renderCaptcha(0));
$this->set('captcha1', $this->CaptchaGenerator->renderCaptcha(1));
$this->set('captcha2', $this->CaptchaGenerator->renderCaptcha(2));
if ($this->request->is('post')):
    $captchaArray['captcha0flag'] = @$this->request->data['captcha0flag'];
    $captchaArray['captcha1flag'] = @$this->request->data['captcha1flag'];
    $captchaArray['captcha2flag'] = @$this->request->data['captcha2flag'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($captchaArray); $i++) {
        $responseValue[] = $this->CaptchaGenerator->checkCaptcha($captchaArray, $i);
    }
    pr($responseValue);
```

On pr($responseValue) I get this result

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)

It means that value from 3 boxes are true. Then I am trying to save my post and tags if this values are true using this code

```
if ($responseValue == 1) {
    if (isset($temp)) {
        $this->Tag->saveMany($temp);
    }
    $listOfId = $this->Tag->tagIdArray;
    $this->request->data['Claim']['Tag'] = $listOfId;
    $this->Claim->save($this->request->data);
    $this->redirect('/');
}
else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Nop', 'flash', array('alert' => 'error'));
    $this->redirect('/start-claim');
}
```

But still it is not allwoing to submit post my showing flash message "NOP". can any one suggest me????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at all unset the values at when you don't need them any more and you are getting values of $responseArray as array so insted of $responseArray == 1 use following code and i am sure it will help you :)

Always unset data soon after you don't need them anymore

```
if($responseValue[0] && $responseValue[1] && $responseValue[2] == 1) {
                ........
            }
            else {
                ..........
            }
            unset($this->request->data['captcha0flag']);
            unset($this->request->data['captcha1flag']);
            unset($this->request->data['captcha2flag']);
```

Happy coading :)

Comment: Thank You...Your answer is really helpfull..It is working now.